# Get product changes

Tags: magento

Situation is:

Admin logs in to system and he changes product somehow.

For example:

Sets qty to 10
Adds 2 images
Changes description

Is there any way to track these changes? Well I mean exactly track WHAT and HOW admin changed?

I use Magento CE 1.6

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can find the unaltered data through an object's [`getOrigData()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Object/Varien_Object.html#getOrigData) method. A good time to get the object is through it's save_before event, so [create an observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method#step_4) for the `catalog_product_save_before` event. The observer might contain the following:

```php
public function onCatalogProductSaveBefore($observer)
{
  $product = $observer->getProduct();
  if ($product->hasDataChanges()) {
    $newValues = array_diff_assoc($product->getData(), $product->getOrigData());
    $oldValues = array_diff_assoc($product->getOrigData(), $product->getData());
    $added     = array_diff_key($product->getData(), $product->getOrigData());
    $unset     = array_diff_key($product->getOrigData(), $product->getData());
  }
}
```

Note that `$newValues` will include all of `$added` and existing attributes that have had their value changed. Ditto for `$oldValues` and `$unset`.

Comment: catalog_product_save_before getOrigData() are the way to go with. TY ;)

Comment: I think instead of using array_diff it should be array_diff_assoc

Comment: I think you could be right. Using `array_diff` would have worked in some cases though.

Comment: This is throwing en exception for me "Array to string conversion". It is because the getData() array contains "stock_item" which is an object. This causes an error at array_diff_assoc/array_diff function because the parameters to these functions should be arrays

Comment: Would it work for group price delete ? or tier price delete ?

Comment: @RedDevil It won't work because prices have their own class, `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price`.  The price class is not a descendant of `Varien_Object` so it does not have the old prices for you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can find unaltered data through getOrigData() as pointed out by clockworkgeek but Magento has a build in function to compare and check if the data has been changed. The method is called dataHasChangedFor() and you have to pass the property that you want to check.
It would look somthing like this.

```
$isChanged = $productData->dataHasChangedFor('description'); 
if ($isChanged) { 
// do somthing 
}
```

here the method dataHasChanged() will return boolean value based on whether the data was altered.

Comment: This answer is the most useful, as it's using Magento 1.9 (OpenMage)'s built in comparison tool.

Answer (score 2):

just in case some people still coming up to this one:
@clockworkgeek's answer is not correct, as soon as you turn on developer mode and displaying errors (php>=5.4) you will get exceptions and warnings:

`Array to string conversion in...`

as solution for recursive comparison:

```
public function onCatalogProductSaveBefore($observer)
{
  $product = $observer->getProduct();
  if ($product->hasDataChanges()) {
    $newValues = $this->_compareArrayAssocRecursive($product->getData(), $product->getOrigData());
    $oldValues = $this->_compareArrayAssocRecursive($product->getOrigData(), $product->getData());
  }
}

protected function _compareArrayAssocRecursive($array1, $array2) 
{
    $diff = array();
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (!isset($array2[$key]) || !is_array($array2[$key])) {
                $diff[$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $newDiff = $this->_compareArrayAssocRecursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                if (!empty($newDiff)) {
                    $diff[$key] = $newDiff;
                }
            }
        } elseif (!array_key_exists($key,$array2) || $array2[$key] !== $value) {
            $diff[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $diff;
}
```

Hope that helps
Personally i would recommend to put that function into a helper class and make it public :)

**UPDATE**:
according to problems with numeric values was float and decimal the better solution would be:

```
/**
 * return diff according to product changes 
 * 
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @return array
 */
protected function _compareArrayAssocRecursive($product)
{
    $diff = array();
    $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getEditableAttributes($product);

    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        if ($product->dataHasChangedFor($key)) {
            $diff[$key] = $product->getData($key);
        }
    }
    return $diff;
}
```