# How to find which admin user posted the product?

Tags: magento, admin

Currently Im working on a magento project and it have a plugin developed by another team. This project have merchant logins also. But the issue I am facing now is. When I add a product from merchant panel, it is not getting displayed in his product list. It is shown in admin product list. I want to track down what userid is entering corresponding to that record inserting from merchant login.

In which table I have look? After searching a lot I believe they are not storing any userid corresponding to each product. But I am not sure about that. How can I confirm that?

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in magento admin, as far as I know. But you can write your own module to controller_action_predispatch or to core_abstract_model_save_after(or something like this) events. And you will be able to see who did what.

**UPDATE 1**

If I am right, meaning this is not implemented, then you should your own custom logging module.

Module should use Observer functionality. If you want particullarly catch the product save, then you should catch the events of product saving.

[here](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-event-observer-with-save-before-and-save-after/).

To compare product data you can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182009/get-product-changes).

Well to get current user you can read [this example](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-admin-user-id-name-username-email-etc/).

Moreover in case it is not enough, you may watch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425416/stopping-product-saving-process-in-observer), something might be interestring for you.

Comment: Hi Jevgeni, Thanks for your reply. Im not searching for an option from admin panel. I want to know is there any table in magento where I can find the product and admin user id relation. Means which admin user posted the product.?

Comment: If there is no such thing. How can I implement that?